# Collision detection in javascript game

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a little platform game. But it's not going really well with the collision detection. I've looked at many tutorials on this but is can't seem to understand it. Here's my code:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
var rightPressed =false;
var spacePressed =false;
var leftPressed=false;
var gravity = 1;
//Player object
var player = {
  x:50,
  y:370,
  dy:0,
  dx:0,
  width:10,
  height:10,
  speed:10,
  jumping:false
};
//Box object
var box ={
  x:200,
  y:350,
  width:50,
  height:50
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUp);

function keyDown(e) {
  if(e.keyCode ==39){
    rightPressed=true;
  }
  if (e.keyCode ==32){
    spacePressed=true;
  }
  if (e.keyCode ==37){
    leftPressed =true;
  }
}
function keyUp(e) {
  if(e.keyCode ==39){
    rightPressed=false;
  }
  if (e.keyCode ==32){
    spacePressed=false;
  }
  if (e.keyCode ==37){
    leftPressed =false;
  }
}
//Draw the ball
function drawBall(){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(player.x,player.y,10,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.fillStyle="red";
  ctx.fill();
}
//Draw the box
function drawBox() {
  ctx.fillRect(box.x,box.y,box.width,box.height);
}
//The main function that calls the other functions and handles the logic
function draw(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  drawBall();
  drawBox();
  if (rightPressed){
    //Right speed of the ball
    player.x+=5;
  }
  if(leftPressed){
    //Left speed of the ball
    player.x-=5;
  }
  if(spacePressed){
    if(!player.jumping){
      //The hight of the jump 
      player.dy=-player.speed * 2;
      player.jumping = true;

    }
  }
  player.dy+=gravity;

  player.x+=player.dx;
  player.y+=player.dy;

  if(player.y >= 390){
    player.y = 390;
    player.jumping = false;
  }
  //Box collision logic

  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw)
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```css
canvas {border:1px solid black;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400px" height="400px"> </canvas>
```

[CODEPEN HERE](https://codepen.io/vuxer/pen/dOEJKp)

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking here, are you trying to detect collision with the box?

Comment: There actually isn't any collision detection being done in the code...

Comment: Yes I am, and I know there isn't :D because everything that I've tried didn't make sense do I deleted it.

Comment: The basic concept is very easy, for moving right: `if (player.x+(player.width/2) >= box.x) {console.log("collision!");}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when i try that, the player doesn't just collide with the box, he collides with the air above it too. Now I've tried from all sides, but that doesn't work either because I want to make him stop when he hits the box from the left or right, but not when he stands on it.

Comment: I'll cook something up for you today or tomorrow, it's possible with a little tweaking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the behaviour you're looking for. The following code does all the magic:
*(see the code snippet below for a working demo)*

```
//CHECK COLLISION
var collisionObjects = [rect.box, rect.wall];
for (var i=0,count=collisionObjects.length; i<count; ++i) {
    var obj = collisionObjects[i];
    var playerLeft=x-player.width, playerRight=x+player.width, playerTop=y-player.height, playerBottom=y+player.height;
    var objectLeft=obj.x, objectRight=obj.x+obj.width, objectTop=obj.y, objectBottom=obj.y+obj.height;
    //check if player is either touching or within the object-bounds
    if (playerRight>=objectLeft && playerLeft<=objectRight && playerBottom>=objectTop && playerTop<=objectBottom) {
        if (player.y+player.height==objectTop || player.y-player.height==objectBottom) {y=player.y;} //player is already colliding with top or bottom side of object
        else if (player.x+player.width==objectLeft || player.x-player.width==objectRight) {x=player.x;} //player is already colliding with left or right side of object
        else if (playerRight>objectLeft && playerLeft<objectRight && playerBottom>objectTop && playerTop<objectBottom) {
            //check on which side the player collides with the object
            var sides = {left:Math.abs(playerRight-objectLeft), right:Math.abs(playerLeft-objectRight), top:Math.abs(playerBottom-objectTop), bottom:Math.abs(playerTop-objectBottom)};
            var side = Math.min(sides.left, sides.right, sides.top, sides.bottom); //returns the side with the smallest distance between player and object
            if (side==sides.top) {y=objectTop-player.height;} else if (side==sides.left) {x=objectLeft-player.width;} //first check top, than left
            else if (side==sides.bottom) {y=objectBottom+player.height;} else if (side==sides.right) {x=objectRight+player.width;} //first check bottom, than right
        }
    }
}
```

But in order for this to work, I had to change some other things too:

- Instead of directly updating `player.x` and `player.y`, I had to create variables `x` and `y` at the start of draw, and only at the and update `player.x=x, player.y=y`.
  So the whole function `draw()` should be copied I think to be save.

But don't blindly copy it, I also made some other changes, mostly for my own understanding and readability of your script. Do with that what you want.. you like it, copy it, you don't, leave it:

- I changed `player.speed` into `player.speedx` and `player.speedy`. These properties are also used in `draw()`, so be careful with that.
- I added variables `floor` and `end`, to restrict the ball from leaving the canvas.
- I changed the `gravity` value to the gravity value on earth.
- I changed `var box` to `var rect`, an object containing all rectangular shapes. If you want to place a new rectangle, just add a new one in the `rect` object and that's it.
  In `draw()` I changed `drawBox();` to `for (key in rect) {if (rect.hasOwnProperty(key)) {drawRect(rect[key]);}}`, a loop that draws all the objects that are inside the `rect` object.
- `var collisionObjects = [rect.box, rect.wall];` is an array that contains all the objects that should trigger a collision with the player.
  As you can see in the demo, the yellow `shelf` doesn't trigger a collision, because it is not in the array.
  *(If you do add the `shelf` to the collisionObjects-array, the ball still falls through after about half a second, I haven't figured out why. I thought it had to do with the width (`height` in code), but that's not it. For some reason, if the object doesn't touch the floor, the ball will eventually fall through.)*

**Code snippet:**

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
//OBJECTS====================
var player = {x:50,y:100, dx:0,dy:0, width:10,height:10, speedx:5,speedy:10, jumping:false, color:"red"};
var rect = {
 box: {x:150,y:350, width:50,height:50, color:"blue"},
 shelf: {x:220,y:250, width:60,height:5, color:"gold"},
 wall: {x:360,y:300, width:10,height:100, color:"green"}
};
//VARS====================
var rightPressed = false;
var spacePressed = false;
var leftPressed = false;
var gravity = 0.98;
var floor = canvas.height-player.height;
var end = canvas.width-player.width;

//KEY-HANDLERS====================
document.addEventListener("keydown",function(e) {
 if (e.keyCode==39) {rightPressed=true;} //RIGHT
 if (e.keyCode==37) {leftPressed=true;} //LEFT
 if (e.keyCode==32) {spacePressed=true;} //JUMP
});
document.addEventListener("keyup",function(e) {
 if (e.keyCode==39) {rightPressed=false;} //RIGHT
 if (e.keyCode==37) {leftPressed=false;} //LEFT
 if (e.keyCode==32) {spacePressed=false;} //JUMP
});

//DRAW====================
//OBJECTS--------------------
function drawPlayer() {
 ctx.fillStyle = player.color;
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(player.x,player.y,10,0,Math.PI*2);
 ctx.fill();
}
function drawRect(obj) {
 ctx.fillStyle = obj.color;
 ctx.fillRect(obj.x,obj.y,obj.width,obj.height);
}
//SCENE--------------------
function draw() {
 ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
 drawPlayer(); //draw player
 for (key in rect) {if (rect.hasOwnProperty(key)) {drawRect(rect[key]);}} //draw all objects in 'rect'
 
 //MOVE PLAYER
 var x=player.x, y=player.y;
 if (rightPressed) {x = x+player.speedx;} //right
 if (leftPressed) {x = x-player.speedx;} //left
 if (spacePressed && !player.jumping) { //jump
  player.jumping = true;
  player.dy = -player.speedy * 2; //jump-factor
 }
 
 x = x+player.dx;
 if (x <= player.width) {x=player.width;}
 if (x >= end) {x=end;}
 
 player.dy += gravity;
 y = y+player.dy;
 if (y >= floor) {y=floor; player.jumping=false;}
 
 //CHECK COLLISION
 var collisionObjects = [rect.box, rect.wall];
 for (var i=0,count=collisionObjects.length; i<count; ++i) {
  var obj = collisionObjects[i];
  var playerLeft=x-player.width, playerRight=x+player.width, playerTop=y-player.height, playerBottom=y+player.height;
  var objectLeft=obj.x, objectRight=obj.x+obj.width, objectTop=obj.y, objectBottom=obj.y+obj.height;
  //check if player is either touching or within the object-bounds
  if (playerRight>=objectLeft && playerLeft<=objectRight && playerBottom>=objectTop && playerTop<=objectBottom) {
   if (player.y+player.height==objectTop || player.y-player.height==objectBottom) {y=player.y;} //player is already colliding with top or bottom side of object
   else if (player.x+player.width==objectLeft || player.x-player.width==objectRight) {x=player.x;} //player is already colliding with left or right side of object
   else if (playerRight>objectLeft && playerLeft<objectRight && playerBottom>objectTop && playerTop<objectBottom) {
    //check on which side the player collides with the object
    var sides = {left:Math.abs(playerRight-objectLeft), right:Math.abs(playerLeft-objectRight), top:Math.abs(playerBottom-objectTop), bottom:Math.abs(playerTop-objectBottom)};
    var side = Math.min(sides.left, sides.right, sides.top, sides.bottom); //returns the side with the smallest distance between player and object
    if (side==sides.top) {y=objectTop-player.height;} else if (side==sides.left) {x=objectLeft-player.width;} //first check top, than left
    else if (side==sides.bottom) {y=objectBottom+player.height;} else if (side==sides.right) {x=objectRight+player.width;} //first check bottom, than right
    player.jumping=false;
   }
  }
 }
 //SET PLAYER POSITION
 player.x=x, player.y=y;
 
 //NEXT FRAME--------------------
 requestAnimationFrame(draw)
} draw();
```

```css
canvas {border:1px solid black;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400px" height="400px"></canvas>
```

**codepen:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bByQJg?editors=0010
**jsfiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/zvkgnegt/8/

Answer (score 0):

So I know this isn't going to be helping you fix your code, but I would highly recommend you check out http://wickeditor.com/  if you look at the demo on the front page (click to like the 4th one) you will see it offers great collision detection, you can download the project from the site and it should make it super easy to replicate to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but yea that didn't help me much :(

Comment: Did you download the project and look into it?

Comment: Yup, and it's a huuuuuge program. And it does collision detection, but not side-specific if you get what I mean.